# Silverlight and "z-index"

Tags: jquery, silverlight

I have a Silverlight clickable map and a sliding panel (jquery) that drops down.  Despite giving the panel a high z-index, it still slots behind the silverlight app.

You can see this here:
[Problem in action...](http://www.encephalitis.info/Community/ContactRR.aspx)

To activate the sliding panel, click "Translate" at the very top left of the window.

Is there anyway to let such a "sliding panel" cover up my silverlight app?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (FF 3.6). Have you found a cure already? Are you looking at it in a particular browser? You left out any kind of hint about where the sliding panel might be. I found one for the menu that has the items Search, Translate, etc. Is that the one that gave you trouble?

Comment: what triggers the sliding panel? I'm trying to replicate and having a hard time doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to set the Silverlight plugin object to be [windowless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156%28VS.95%29.aspx). Take note of the limitations listed on that page, as setting the plugin to windowless comes at a cost (e.g. performance).